# Face coloring in Matlab revisited

Tags: function, matlab, patch

Using Mathematica I was able to create [the following plot](http://arkadiusz-jadczyk.eu/images/sferka.jpg)

Now I would like to switch to Matlab - which I am just starting to learn. I was able to create the triangulation with FL.vertices and FL.faces matrix and the patch function, that looks like this

```
faces=FV.faces; 
facecolor = [.7 .7 .7]; 
patch('faces',faces,'vertices',FV.vertices,...
'facecolor',facecolor,'facealpha',0.8,'edgecolor',[.8.8.8]);
camlight('headlight','infinite'); 
daspect([1 1 1]); axis vis3d; axis off 
material dull;
```

It produces a dull [image](http://arkadiusz-jadczyk.eu/images/matlabsphere.jpg):

Now, I have a function J that takes the matrix FL.vertices and returns a matrix of positive values. I would like to color the faces according to the values of J on vertices. Possibly interpolate along the faces. Edges can be, for now, as they are - to deal with later. After reading the documentation it is not clear to me how to accomplish this task. Do I need to find min and max of J manually? Or can Matlab do it automatically? It is OK for now to use one of Matlab's preset coloring schemes, something like a "temperature map" would do. At which point should I call my function J? How exactly it should be used with the patch command? I looked through the previous answers to a similar question, but still I am not able to figure out how to deal with my case. Any helping suggestion will be appreciated.

P.S.
OK. I think I did it with simple

```
FV.Cdata=sphere_jacobian(FV.vertices,1,1,0,1);
figure
Hp = patch('faces',FV.faces,'vertices',FV.vertices,...
'FaceVertexCData',FV.Cdata,'facecolor','interp','edgecolor',[.8 .8 .8]);
```

But I am not sure if min and max have been automatically computed and interpolated.

Comment: OK. I think I did it with simple

Comment: have you tried changing the `colormap`?

Comment: Will try playing with the colormap. I think I really need to do some scaling of my coloring function. Also I would like to plot the contours of my function on this colored sphere. Could not find the right example anywhere.

Comment: Could you be more clear about what exactly you want to ask? Or if you have already found the solution please post it as an answer.

Comment: Inded, I think I have fond the answer: I did colormap(hsv(3200)); and normalized my function: jac = sphere_jacobian(FV.vertices,m); minj = min(jac);maxj = max(jac);jac1 = (jac-minj*ones(size(jac)))/(maxj-minj);FV.Cdata=jac1;
figure 
Hp = patch('faces',FV.faces,'vertices',FV.vertices,...
  'FaceVertexCData',FV.Cdata,'facecolor','interp','edgecolor',[.8 .8 .8]);
The result can be seen [here](http://arkadiusz-jadczyk.eu/images/26-Dec-12%2021-37-20.jpg). Not quite optimal, but not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I believe to be the answer given by the poster, I will put it here so the question does not remain open.

OK. I think I did it with simple

```
FV.Cdata=sphere_jacobian(FV.vertices,1,1,0,1);
figure
Hp = patch('faces',FV.faces,'vertices',FV.vertices,...
'FaceVertexCData',FV.Cdata,'facecolor','interp','edgecolor',[.8 .8 .8]);
```

But I am not sure if min and max have been automatically computed and interpolated.

---

I did

```
colormap(hsv(3200));
```

and normalized my function:

```
jac = sphere_jacobian(FV.vertices,m); 
minj = min(jac);
maxj = max(jac);
jac1 = (jac-minj*ones(size(jac)))/(maxj-minj);FV.Cdata=jac1; 
figure Hp = patch('faces',FV.faces,'vertices',FV.vertices,... 'FaceVertexCData',FV.Cdata,'facecolor','interp','edgecolor',[.8 .8 .8]);
```

The result can be seen [here](http://arkadiusz-jadczyk.eu/images/26-Dec-12%2021-37-20.jpg).